# What is an absolutely conformal mapping?

Tags: terminology

Is it simply a retronym for ‘conformal mapping’ – to insure its distinction from
that of an ‘anti-conformal mapping’?

A google search for ‘anti-conformal mapping’ brings up also references to articles on ‘absolutely conformal mappings’ (plural), but a google search for ‘absolutely conformal mapping’ (singular) gives no hits. Hence, my query.

Comment: It's hard to guess without knowing the context where you encountered this terminology.

Comment: Anti-conformal mapping appears to be the product of an anti-holomorphic function. Perhaps this will help in your search or, you might find what you are looking for in the answer to a similar question. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535302/anti-holomorphic-significance