# Differential equation for harmonic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that a harmonic function satisfies the formal differential equation: $$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z \partial \overline{z}}=0$$

### Question

How is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ even defined when $u$ isn't constant. It is clear that for any non-constant complex variabled, real valued, analytic function $u$ we have that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ is not defined. This comes from Cauchy-Riemann equations. So how does this question make sense?

Comment: [This might help.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268745/how-exactly-does-frac-partial-f-partial-barz-work)

Comment: They are defined, but maybe not the way you think.  By definition, $$\eqalign{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)\cr
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}} &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the notation that Robert Israel mentioned you can restate the equation as

$$\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}}=\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \right]\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right]=\frac{1}{4}\left[\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-i\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y\partial x}+i\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right].$$

Can you complete it from here?